# JsonIgnore child property from parent

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, swagger

I am trying to ignore when serializing to Json a parent property on a child class but it is not working.

I have an object like this:

```
public class DependantQuestionCreateRequest : QuestionCreateRequest
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new DependantQuestionCreateRequest DependantQuestion;

}
```

As you can see, I am hiding the parent property DependantQuestion just for adding a JsonIgnore attibute to the child property.

This is because both classes are equal, the only difference is that the parent, can contain a child inside as property, but the child can not.

I don't want to duplicate all the props from one model to another just to avoid serializing on swagger the DependantQuestion property.

This code is not working though, and my swagger displays it like

```
"dependantQuestion" : "string"
```

This means in my opinion, the JsonIgnore attribute is getting actually ignored.

Does anyone know a way to hide this parent property on the child?

Comment: Try using virutal/override and override the property in a child instead of hiding it with a keyword `new`

Comment: Yes, with virtual/override [this works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jy2yNh)

Comment: Thank you guys. It is working :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution providen by @gunr2171 and @Fabjan on the comments, answers my question.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string MyProperty {get;set;} 
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public override string MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```